# Waiting time for a pattern in coin tossing

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $\{X_t\}$ be an iid sequence of fair coin tosses and $\tau_{HTH} = \inf\{t\geq 3: X_{t-2}X_{t-1}X_t=HTH\}$. I want to determine $E\tau_{HTH}$.

I don't understand a part of the explanation which is:

Gamblers place bets on each individual toss. On each bet, gambler pays an entrance fee of $k$ and is paid $2k$ in return if the outcome is $H$ or $0$ if the outcome is $T$. $k$ can be negative which corresponds to a bet on $T$.

Suppose that at each unit of time until $HTH$ first appears, a new gambler enters and employs the following strategy: on his first bet, he wagers $1$ on $H$. If he loses, he stops. If he wins and $HTH$ has not yet appeared, he wagers his payoff of $2$ on $T$. If he loses, he stops. If he wins and $HTH$ has not yet appeared, he wagers his payoff of $4$ on $H$. This is the last bet placed bu this particular gambler.

The gambler who started at $\tau_{HTH}$ is paid $2$ and the gambler who started at $\tau_{HTH}-2$ is paid $8$ and every gambler has paid an initial entry fee of $1$. At time $\tau_{HTH}$, the net profit to all gamblers $=10-\tau_{HTH}$ and since the game is fair $E\tau_{HTH}=10$

> Q1) I can see that the net profit for all gamblers is $10-\tau_{HTH}$ if the outcome string is say $TTTHTH$ and this wouldn't be the net profit if atleast one $H$ appears before $HTH$, am I correct? (say the outcome string is $HHHHTH$).
>
> Q2) The explanation also says $\tau_{HTH}/3$ is bounded by a Geometric(1/8) random variable. How can I see that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the outcome is $HHHHTH$, then the first gambler will win their first bet, then bet all of their winnings on the second toss being a $T$, and then lose everything, having a total loss of their initial payment of $1$.

The second gambler will win their first bet, then lose the second bet on exactly the same way as the first gambler, having a total loss of $1$.

In fact, of the six gamblers, each one of them has paid an initial $1$ to enter the game, and only the fourth and sixth have come away with winnings ($10$ in total). So the net win for all the gamblers is indeed $10-6=4$.

In general, it turns out that only the last and the third-from-last gambler can walk away with winnings: The moment any gambler wins their $8$, the game stops because we reached $HTH$, the last gambler walks away with their $2$, and every other gambler has lost,

As for question $2$, consider the following alternative game (forgetting the gamblers): Toss a coin three times. If you got $HTH$, stop, and if not, try again. Keep going until you have gotten a triple of $HTH$. Say it takes $\sigma_{HTH}$ triples before you stop. Can you see that this is a geometric random variable?

Now say both of these games were being played simultaneously with the same coin tosses. Can you see why $\tau_{HTH}\leq 3\sigma_{HTH}$?

Comment: Thanks, I see that now.

Comment: With this gambling strategy, $E\tau_{HTH} = 10$, may I know the rationale for this strategy? I am thinking the expectation would be different with another strategy.

Comment: @manifolded The gambling is a game played on top of the coin tossing, but doesn't affect it at all. So regardless of gambling strategies, you get $E\tau_{HTH}=10$. The choice of gambling strategy just affects how easy that result is to find.

Comment: I see, one last question, how about the payout? Why was the payout designed to double the wager until the gambler loses? If the payout is, say $4$ times the wager, then if the outcome is $TTTHTH$, then the net win for all gamblers would be $64+4-6$, right?

Comment: @manifolded It was designed that way to be easy to calculate. In means everyone pays $1$ to participate, and then win back either $0,2,4$ or $8$ in a simple pattern. In your suggestion, gamblers would pay $1$ to participate, then if they won, they would pay even more to participate in round $2$, and so on. It's not as easy to work with.

Comment: I am a little confused then, sorry, if the payout is $4$ times the wager, then $E\tau_{HTH} = 68$?

Comment: @manifolded Sorry, I didn't read your comment well enough. I thought you were talking about a different gambling scheme, not a different gambling game. If the payout was four times the wager, the game wouldn't be fair. So the expected winnings for any given gambler, and thus the expected total net winnings wouldn't be $0$. So the argument wouldn't work as nicely.

Comment: Understood, thanks!

Comment: @manifolded In any given bet, you have a $50\%$ chance of a net loss of $k$, and $50\%$ chance of net wins of $k$. It's quite easy to use the definition of expectation to see that the expected net winnings is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

We can handle the case of a possibly unfair coin using generating functions.

A pattern for all sequences ending in $HTH$ is
$$
T^\ast\left(H^\ast(HTT)T^\ast\right)^\ast H^\ast HTH\tag1
$$
where $(\dots)^\ast$ represents $0$ or more sequences matching $(\dots)$.

The generating function for $(1)$ is
$$
\overbrace{\ \frac1{1-qx}\ }^{T^\ast}\overbrace{\frac1{1-\underbrace{\frac1{1-px}pq^2x^3\frac1{1-qx}}_{H^\ast(HTT)T^\ast}}}^{\left(H^\ast(HTT)T^\ast\right)^\ast}\overbrace{\ \frac1{1-px}\ }^{H^\ast}\overbrace{\ \ p^2qx^3\ \ \vphantom{\frac11}}^{HTH}\tag2
$$
where $p$ is the probability of an $H$ and $q=1-p$ is the probability of a $T$.

That is,
$$
\begin{align}
g(x)
&=\frac{p^2(1-p)x^3}{1-x+p(1-p)x^2-p(1-p)^2x^3}\tag3\\[9pt]
g(1)
&=1\tag4\\[9pt]
%g'(x)
%&=\frac{p^2(1-p)x^2\left(3-2x+p(1-p)x^2\right)}{\left(1-x+p(1-p)x^2-p(1-p)^2x^3\right)^2}\\
g'(1)
&=\frac{1+p(1-p)}{p^2(1-p)}\tag5\\[3pt]
%g''(x)
%&=\frac{2p^2(1-p)x\left(3-3x+\left(1-p+p^2\right)x^2+6p(1-p)^2x^3-3p(1-p)^2x^4+p^2(1-p)^3x^5\right)}{\left(1-x+p(1-p)x^2-p(1-p)^2x^3\right)^3}\\
g''(1)
&=\frac{2+4p-8p^2+6p^4-2p^5}{p^4(1-p)^2}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
The mean duration is
$$
g'(1)=\frac{1+p(1-p)}{p^2(1-p)}\,\overset{p\to\frac12}\to\,10\tag7
$$
The duration variance is
$$
g''(1)+g'(1)-g'(1)^2=\frac{1+p(1-p)\left(2-4p-2p^2+p^3\right)}{p^4(1-p)^2}\,\overset{p\to\frac12}\to\,58\tag8
$$

Comment: A pattern for $HTT$ is $T^\ast\left(H^\ast HT\right)^\ast H^\ast HTT$ with $g(x)=\frac{p(1-p)^2x^3}{1-x+p(1-p)^2x^3}$

Comment: A pattern for $HHT$ is $T^\ast\left(HTT^\ast\right)^\ast H^\ast HHT$ with $g(x)=\frac{p^2(1-p)x^3}{1-x+p^2(1-p)x^3}$